# The selected component glows in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When I click the component with the mouse, the component will show a glowing effect. Similar to the following effect:
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=bl#webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom_selective

In three.js, I can achieve the effect in the link, but when I try to integrate into the forge viewer, I encountered difficulties, because the version of three.js used in the forge viewer is: 71

Does anyone know how it can be achieved? Or someone who has ideas can communicate together. Looking forward to your answers, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The bloom effect looks really neat. Unfortunately the Forge Viewer rendering pipeline is not customizable, especially when it comes to post-processing effects.

The only way I can think of that would allow you achieving this kind of effect would be using something like the [AR/VR Toolkit](http://forgetoolkit.com/#/), bringing your Forge models to a Unity app, and customize the visuals in there.